# ServiceStackController in MVC 5 Viewbag null after default constructor sets values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack, viewbag

I am using ServiceStack with my MVC5 Application.

I have all of my controllers inherit from the ServiceStackController.
In the app host I am registering:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
```

I have a TestController with a default constructor:

```
        public TestController()
        {            
            this.testClass= new TestClass();

            ViewBag.Title = "Some Title";
        }
```

Then I have a test action result.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    //Viewbag.Title ... at this point the Viewbag.Title is null.  
    //Actually the whole Viewbag is empty.  What could be resetting it?
    //....
}
```

I know it is related to ServiceStack because if I comment out the ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container)); then I do not have any issue.  The Viewbag retains the Title that was set in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed in the latest **v4.0.31** release of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)